# What cpaenl like softwares are available for MERN stack?

Tags: cpanel, digital-ocean, mern, paas, caprover

I want to launch multiple MERN projects from a single Digital Ocean server. I am now searching for self host cpanel like PaaS I can use to maintain my MERN projects. Can you guys suggest what software should I use?

In my research I found caprover can be  a good solution, but I am not sure which one to pick.

Answer (score 0):

See specifically for mern there is no control panel available in market but the best you can try is without any control panel directly on vps (If you vast knowledge in server and routing stuff) else install aapanel, and it gets the most of the job done it has UI for all your need